# Why is xltabr not running?

Tags: r

[xltabr](https://moj-analytical-services.github.io/xltabr/) seems to be the only way to create excel contingency tables in R.

I am trying to use this write out a contingency tab to excel, but the auto_crosstab_to_wb command has been running for over an hour with no result. (I see the red icon on the console indicating that it is still running). I realize now that it is something to do with my studio/packages, so it's hard to reproduce the problem.

See here for the code required to reproduce the problem with xltabr:

```
    devtools::install_github("moj-analytical-services/xltabr")
    library(reshape2)
    library(Rcpp)
    iris
    ct <- reshape2::dcast(iris, Sepal.Length ~ Species, fun.aggregate = length, value.var = "Sepal.Length")
    wb <- xltabr::auto_crosstab_to_wb(ct) # this is the line taking hours to run
```

1. Any idea why this could be happening (to just me)? I updated all my packages but still no difference. What else can I do to debug this? I don't see any warnings so it's really baffling.
2. Is there any other function that allows one to write multiple contingency tables to either excel or csv? This is helpful: [crosstable() export to csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776110/crosstable-export-to-csv) but I have to run append hundreds of tables & I know this is a [real pain to do in R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34643888/how-do-i-append-data-from-a-data-frame-in-r-to-an-excel-sheet-that-already-exist)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Worked for me in less than a second.

Comment: Have you ever tried the package {crosstable}? It seems it would do what you want and it comes with exporting to Excel. You can read more on the doc: https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable.

Comment: @Dan Chaltiel
Crosstable can't be written to excel can it? That is my main issue... I need my output in excel

Comment: I ran your code, it took only a few seconds, I have no idea why it would take so long on your computer. However, the result is not at all what I expected, what is your expected output for your `iris` example exactly? Of note, `crosstable::crosstable()` can be exported to excel easily, but I have no idea about `xltabr`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I un-installed and re-installed R studio, and updated every package. For some reason, this seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the package `{crosstable}`.

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of this package.*

Your code is calculating a contingency table on all values of `Sepal.Length` depending on values of `Species`. By default, crosstable will consider `Sepal.Length` numerical so you have to use `unique_numeric=Inf` to override the behavior. Also, crosstable will calculate proportion by default, you can prevent this using `margin=-1`.

You can search for even more options in [the documentation](https://danchaltiel.github.io/crosstable/).

Here is the result. I use `as_flextable()` to output an HTML table, which is more readable on StackOverflow but you don't have to.

```r
library(crosstable)
crosstable(iris, Sepal.Length, by=Species, unique_numeric=Inf, margin=-1) %>% as_flextable()
```

[image: crosstable 2]

```r
wb = crosstable(iris, Sepal.Length, by=Species, unique_numeric=Inf, margin=-1) %>% as_workbook()
openxlsx::saveWorkbook(wb, "crosstable.xlsx")
```

[image]

However, your example makes little sense to me, do you really want to treat a numeric variable as a categorical one? I think this has more sense using default values in crosstable, hence calculating summaries (which you could choose if you want):

```r
crosstable(iris, Sepal.Length, by=Species) %>% as_flextable()
```

[image: crosstable 1]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>